# Unexpected output while converting numbers to words

Tags: c

I am new to C and I have to write a loop that prints a number in words from a given integer between 0 and 9. And the loop should stop if the input is equal to '#'.

Exemple:

```
input: 1
output: ONE
```

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main() {

    char tableau[10][5] = {"ZERO","ONE","TWO","THREE","FOUR","FIVE","SIX","SEVEN","EIGHT","NINE"};

    char nb[1];

    while (nb[0] != '#') {
        printf("nb = ");
        scanf("%c", &nb[0]);
        printf("%s\n", tableau[atoi(nb)]);
    }
}
```

returns

```
nb = 5
FIVE
nb = ZERO
nb =
```

The expected output should be:

```
nb = 5
Five
nb =
```

Everything works except the line "nb = ZERO" shouldn't be there.

Comment: FYI: `"EIGHT"` takes 6 bytes not 5. Mind the string terminator.

Comment: `atoi` expects a string. `nb` is *not* a string. Where is the zero termination? When you have a fixed-size array of length `1`, there is a hint that you are doing something wrong. Just skip `atoi` and subtract `'0'` from the character value. Naturally after you have verified the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the `scanf` line asked for input, you typed in `5<enter>`, right?

So first it processed the `5`, correctly, and gave output `FIVE`.
Then it processed the `<enter>` (which is character #13)

`atoi(<enter>)` returns `0`.  So it printed out `ZERO`.